# Grabbing an attribute with DOMXPath

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

i know there are lots of way to grabbing an attribute.

this is my html result :

```
<li class="result">
<a class="block_container" href="**FIRST**">
<img alt="changeable text" src="**SOME LINK**" border="0">
</a>
</li>

<li class="result">
<a class="block_container" href="**SECOND**">
<img alt="changeable text" src="**SOME LINK**" border="0">
</a>
</li>


//and many like this ...
```

i can grab (href) but i have many of this attribute !

i used DOMXPath query to help me choose grab first href or second href with item number :

```
$a = $xpath->query("//li[@class='block_container']/a");
echo $text = $a->item(**MY ITEM NUMBER**)->nodeValue;
```

but it doesn't work !

can you help me grab href and src with item number ?

Comment: xpath should be `"//li/a[@class='block_container']".`If you want to get `<img...` it's is not nodeValue, it's innerHTML. While knowing that is always an image, add `/img' to the end of xpath and `echo $dom->saveHTML($a);`

Comment: thank you can you give me example or Edit my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a.href

```
$hrefs = $xpath->query("//li/a[@class='block_container']/@href");
foreach($hrefs as $href) {
  echo $href->nodeValue ."<br>\n";
}
```

and if you want outerHTML of image tag

```
$imgs = $xpath->query("//li/a[@class='block_container']/img");
foreach($imgs as $img) {
  echo $dom->saveHTML($img) ."<br>\n";
}
```

[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/897889)

Comment: but how can i get only second href?

Comment: if you base on my code, it should be `echo $href->item(1)->nodeValue;`  out the foreach